# Table view method cell for row at index path again reloading and then app crashing

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview

In my app I have a table view and 4 images view in one row. When I scroll the table view then cell for row at index path method is again called and then the app crashes. How can I prevent table view reloading when scrolling. My part of code is :-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";


    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier] autorelease];

        for (int i=0; i <= [wordsInSentence count]; ++i) {
            UIImageView *imageView1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30+90*(i%4), 15, 80, 100)] autorelease] ;
            imageView1.tag = i+1;

            [imageViewArray insertObject:imageView1 atIndex:i];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView1];
        }

    }

    int photosInRow;

    if ( (indexPath.row < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1) || ([wordsInSentence count] % 4 == 0) ) {
        photosInRow = 4;
    } else {
        photosInRow = [wordsInSentence count] % 4;
    }

    for ( int i = 1; i <=photosInRow ; i++ ){
        imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:j];
        [self showImage:imageView];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Please help. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Christy

Comment: @Christian Please take some time and format your question. It helps.

Comment: sry will lokk after it in future,please give me the ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see is this,

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= photosInRow ; i++ ){
    imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:j];
    [self showImage:imageView];
}
```

What is `j` here? I suggest you change that to `i` i.e.

```
for ( int i = 1; i <=photosInRow ; i++ ){
    imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:i];
    [self showImage:imageView];
}
```

As such only other flaw I see is the logic here,

```
for (int i=0; i <= [wordsInSentence count]; ++i) {
    UIImageView *imageView1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30+90*(i%4), 15, 80, 100)] autorelease] ;
    imageView1.tag = i+1;

    [imageViewArray insertObject:imageView1 atIndex:i];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView1];
}
```

You only need to add 4 image views in a row. Not the the total number of image views in each row. This is flawed logic. Suggested update to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    UIImageView *imageView1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30+90*(i%4), 15, 80, 100)] autorelease] ;
    imageView1.tag = i+1;

    int trueImageIndex = indexPath.row * 4 + i;
    [imageViewArray insertObject:imageView1 atIndex:trueImageIndex];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView1];
}
```